# Networking: Ask random colleagues for a coffee break?

Tags: new-job, networking, new-hires, break-time

I have just started working in a large consulting firm, together with many other colleagues.

I thought about randomly inviting 3-4 new colleagues to take a coffee break. A good icebreaker would be the fact that we have started the same day.

Would this be a good idea or does it sound a bit weird?

Comment: Considering the extent to which you're overthinking this, are you sure you can ask them without sounding weird? I assume you're working next to these people?

Comment: This needs some context info to answer properly because I'm not sure there's a real question here. VTC unclear until OP adds details.

Comment: I agree with @Lilienthal some context is needed

Answer (score 6):

This would come across as strange to me coming from a random person I barely know. I'd be busy working and wouldn't really appreciate being interrupted for something that's not work related. Different story if we worked together and wanted to take a break.

Comment: Agreed. Start with the folks you already know, and ket your circle expand outward from there. That's how networking works, after all.

Answer (score 3):

If you're on a "saying hi" when you walk past in the hallway basis, you can probably ask to a coffee break (I assume this is at a watering spot in the office). Sometimes I ask colleagues if they want coffee by saying "coffee?" Granted I know these colleagues but the request is very simple. If they decline, let it go.

Answer (score 3):

Consider asking a friendly coworker when/where they usually take their coffee break. Then ask if you can join them and if they will show you where the good stuff is brewed and where the secret stash of half and half is. Be sure to thank them.